# Twitter iOS4 SDK Integration Issue using AddThis SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, addthis

I have integrated the iOS AddThis SDK into my production application but am noticing that with iOS4, the first tweet by a user never gets posted. It is acting like the first tween on iOS4 sets the authorization up as all future tweets work just fine but he first one does not go through.

Is there something I am missing here or is anyone else seeing this issue with the SDK for iOS4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

often twitter does return 401 that might be suppresed by the SDK.  You might want to try using the iOS native twitter API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios).

You might also consider using http://www.getsocialize.com which does all the authentiation/transmitting of the tweet for you.